# e.preventDefault() prevents the kendo 'read' event but does not work for 'create' on update keypress in kendo popup editor

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```
 transport: {
            parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read") {
                    return JSON.stringify(data);
                } else {
                    return (data);
                }
            },
            read: {
                url: function () {
                    return moduleServiceRoot;
                },
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true
            },
            create: {
                url: function (rec) {
                    return moduleServiceRoot; 
                },
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                async: true
            },
            complete: function (e) {
                $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                async: true
            },
        },
        requestStart: function (e) {
            console.log('request started');
            if (e.type == 'create' & validInput == false) {
                console.log('request started');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
```

in the above code validInput is always false. if i comment out the if statement kendo grid read operation is prevented (grid does not show any data) but if i uncomment it, it won't work for kendo create, when i hit update in kendo popup editor.

Comment: I'm not sure if e.preventDefault is the right way to abort an XML HTTP request. Have you tried using the abort method?

Comment: You are right, KendoUI checks for `read` type the return value but not for other events. But agree with @ThilakRao, under which circumstances do you want to cancel the update? Maybe it is easier somewhere else and with less side effects

Comment: @OnaBai I want to cancel the create event if a user tries to add a existing record.I am actually validating user input with values in Database & displaying kendoAlert,Everything is working but not able    to cancel create event as a result duplicate values are getting added in DB.@Thilak Rao no i have not tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create: function (options) {
                if (validInput) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: moduleServiceRoot,
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        async: true,
                        data: JSON.stringify(options.data),
                        success: function (result) {            // notify the data source that the request succeeded,
                            options.success(result);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {              // notify the data source that the request failed
                            options.error(result);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

and it works fine